# return x in case every y is null in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build SQL query that return the value in case the condition is valid on all values, for example :

given this table info:

[image]

I need to return every Name in one condition that the age value for the specific name is always null ,in this example i need to return aa and cc only,  not all age-field values for bb are null(one  of them is 1) ,how do i do it?

```
SELECT I.Name
FROM info I
WHERE I.Name = ALL (SELECT II.Name
                    FROM info II
                    WHERE II.Name = I.Name AND I.Age IS NULL);
```

I've tried something like this, but it's not correct as it returns all the values when their age value was null, and this is not what I wanted.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use aggregation and `having`:

```
select i.name
from info i
group by i.name
having count(i.age) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `GROUP BY` with `having min(Age) is null`

```
select  Name
from    info
group by Name
having  min(Age) is null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to retrieve the entire matching records whose name groups all had `NULL` age values, you could use `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT Serialnumber, Name, Age
FROM
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(Age) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) cnt
    FROM info
) t
WHERE cnt = 0;
```

But, if you just want the matching names, then I would probably go with Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

use  `in`

```
 select *
 from info I
  where I.Name  in (select Name
                      from  info 
                       group by  Name
                       having count(age)=0                       

                        )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/78f13/2

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try using `not exists`:

```
select Name from info i
where not exists(select 1 from info
                 where Name = i.Name and Age is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `ALL`, you can make use of the logical fact that `ALL` elements of an empty set meet whatever criteria:

```
SELECT I.Name
FROM info I
WHERE 1 = ALL (SELECT 0
               FROM info II
               WHERE II.Name = I.Name AND II.Age IS NOT NULL);
```